# Translation Not Happen - Magento CE 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, language

I am learning about translation. I have done below steps to translate one field in product detail page but it did not work. I am not sure about I am going right way

**step1:** copy the **i18n** folder from Magento_Catalog then paste into my custom theme **`<magento-root>`/app/design/frontend/Chennaibox/Theme/**

**step2:** Rename CSV file into fr_FR.csv. In that CSV I have changed second column **QTY** field into **number of materials**

**step3:** change language in admin side to french(france) (Store->Configuration->General->loacle option->local)

**step4:** clear cache,static files then refresh front-end but still QTY only displayed.

What did I wrong here?

**note:** locale(fr_FR)is also generated in pub/static.But I don't know why its not get reflect.

Comment: Can you please tell me which theme is used in frontend side ?

Comment: I used my custom theme which extends to Luma

Comment: I have apply all the above steps, locale change work for me.

Comment: thanks @patel for your great effort to solve this, once again I will do and come back to you

Answer (score 0):

You may try and execute the following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR
```

This will update the contents and make them ready.